# How to perform file write with increment data in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack, fs

I have a list of 80 items and I get 10 item on each page.Now my idea is to write all the data into file in such a way that first 10 will be in one file and then next 10 in another and so on i get 8 pages for my 80 blogs of 10 in each page.The problem is I am getting only one file got written with 10 blogs what about the else.Can anyone please find the error.Thanks.For that I wrote the script as follows,

I find that the loop is not getting incremented.

```
exports.getBlogsTest = function(req, res) {
    helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog');
    var pages = ['undefined', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
        pageNum = '';
    pages.forEach(function(i, v) {
        try {
            var currentPage = Number(i);
            var itemsPerPage = 10;
            var startItem = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
            async.waterfall([
                    function(done) {
                        try {
                            if (currentPage === 1) {
                                blogs.count().exec(function(err, count) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog', err, 'console');
                                        throw err;
                                    } else {
                                        done(err, count);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                done('', 'page');
                            }
                        } catch (e) {
                            helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog', e.message);
                        }
                    },
                    function(count, done) {
                        try {
                            if (count) {
                                if (count && count !== 'page') {
                                    res.setHeader('totalItems', count);
                                }
                                blogs.find().sort({ date: -1 }).select('-text').skip(startItem).limit(itemsPerPage).exec(function(err, data) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog', err, 'console');
                                        throw err;
                                    }
                                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                                        res.send(data);
                                        console.log('reached@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@')
                                        if (i === 'undefined') {
                                            pageNum = '';
                                        } else {
                                            pageNum = i;
                                        }
                                        var fileName = 'public/amp/test2/amp-blog-list' + pageNum + '.html';
                                        var modData = data;
                                        fs.writeFile(fileName, modData, function(err) {
                                            if (err) {
                                                return console.log(err);
                                            }
                                            console.log("The file was saved!");
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        res.send([]);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                res.send([]);
                            }
                        } catch (e) {
                            helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog', e.message);
                        }
                    }
                ],
                function(err) {
                    helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog', err, 'console');
                    throw err;
                });
        } catch (e) {
            helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog', e.message);
        }
    })

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using so many `try catch`? 
While it might be useful in many cases you should avoid using it when not necessary.

A few points where you had an issues:

- `var currentPage = Number(i);`
  when i is 'undefined' currentPage === NaN
- same for `var startItem = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;`
  when currentPage is 'NaN' startItem === NaN

What i guess is that you thought the params in forEach are (index, value) but it's the other way round (value, index)

I tried to improve your code a bit but haven't actualy run it.

```
exports.getBlogsTest = function(req, res) {
    helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog');

    var itemsPerPage = 10;

    for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) { // pages 1-10

        (function(currentPage){ // currentPage = i

            var startItem = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;

            async.waterfall([
                function(done) {
                    if (currentPage === 1) {
                        blogs.count().exec(function(err, count) {
                            if (err) {
                                helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog', err, 'console');
                                //throw err;
                                done(err); // the done callback will be called with the error
                            } else {
                                done(null, count); // no error so send null
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        done(null, 'page'); // no error so send null
                    }
                },
                function(count, done) {
                    if (count) {
                        if (count !== 'page') {
                            res.setHeader('totalItems', count);
                        }
                        blogs.find().sort({ date: -1 }).select('-text').skip(startItem).limit(itemsPerPage).exec(function(err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog', err, 'console');
                                done(err); // you never called done 
                                //throw err;
                            }
                            if (data && data.length > 0) {
                                res.send(data);

                                var fileName = 'public/amp/test2/amp-blog-list' + (currentPage === 1 ? '' : currentPage) + '.html';
                                var modData = data;
                                fs.writeFile(fileName, modData, function(err) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        done(err);
                                        return console.log(err);
                                    }
                                    console.log("The file was saved!");
                                    done(); // you never called done 
                                });
                            } else {
                                res.send([]);
                                done(); // you never called done 
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.send([]);
                        done(); // you never called done 
                    }
                }
            ], function done(err) {
                // this is called when waterfall is done or in case of error
                // it would always throw if you didn't check for error
                // also is it necessary to throw?
                // if (err) throw err;
                helper.logs('getBlogs', 'blog', err, 'console');
            });

        })(i);
    }
};
```